# Mock testing of cobol.net code accessing Main Frame systems

Tags: unit-testing, cobol, cics, cobol.net

I am looking for a way to optimise the unit tests.

The system is written in cobol.net and accesses a Main Frame using CICS universal client.

Is there a way to mock the call to the Main Frame?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Depending on the complexity of the calls, if might be worthwhile writing your own program to simulate the calls.

If you are using Fujitsu's NetCOBOL for .NET, NeoKicks http://www.alchemysolutions.com/products/NeoKicks/overview, might be worth looking at.

Comment: NeoKicks might work if the application only uses CICS as some sort of display manager - if that is all you are getting from CICS you are really short-changing yourself!